# Well defined pullback of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F:M \to N$ be a smooth surjective map between two $C^{\infty}$ manifolds.
Let $Y$ be a vector field on $N$.

Define  the pullback of the  vector field $Y$ by : $$T^\ast Y(p)(f)=Y(F(p))(F\circ f)$$ 
where $f \in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$.

Is this a well defined vector field on $M$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you foresee any issues with whether this is well-defined?

Comment: i see no issues  i just want a confirmation that this is well-defined

Comment: Well, what have you tried? You must have some definition of a vector field. Have you tried checking whether $T^*Y$ fulfills them?

Comment: Note that $F \circ f$ is not defined.